# Rewrite rule that changes only some GET params separated with slashes

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to know how should I write correct RewriteRule that will internally rewrite something like this:

```
http://host/MyFolderForAPI/api/myAction?param1=1&param2=2(...etc...)
```

into this:

```
http://host/MyFolderForAPI/api.php?action=myAction&param1=1&param2=2(...etc...)
```

I wrote .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /MyFolderForAPI/
RewriteRule api/(.*)/?(.*)$ /api.php?action=$1&$2
```

But it doesn't work (I get 404 error).

Rule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^api$ api.php
```

does work, but it only makes half of the work (only hides .php extension but not hides "action=" part.

Comment: First of all, what you want is the other way around than you said it was – you want to rewrite the _incoming_ request with example URL #2 to the format of #1 _internally_. And second of all – of course you get a 404, because `api/myAction` does not match `api/(.*)/?(.*)$`.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Of course I want change URL #2 to URL #1, my mistake. I will edit now.

Comment: I suppose an action is always required? Then just use `^api/(.*)$` in the simplest case, and the flag `QSA` to append the original query string values.

Comment: Yes, action is obligatory, next params are not always and are different in different actions. So, you think something like that: RewriteRule api/(.*)$ /api.php?action=$1 [QSA] should work?